# Isomorphism of first infinitesimal neighborhoods

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

Take an abelian variety $X$ over a field and consider $Z$ to be the first infinitesimal neighborhood of the diagonal in $X\times X$.

Let furthermore $Y$ be the first infinitesimal neighborhood of the point $0$ in $X$.

Then why does one have an isomorphism:

$$Z \simeq X\times Y ?$$